# Error with rails and active admin filter, when filter 'in' is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

how are you? I have a problem with ActiveAdmin, I have a view where I have filterts to search specific records. Like this filters:

`filter :has_open_offers_in, as: :select, label: 'Has buyer offers?', collection: ['Yes', 'No']
filter :expiring_tonight_in, as: :select, label: 'Expires tonight?', collection: ['Yes', 'No']`

If I filter by `has_open_offers_in = 'No'` and `expiring_tonight_in = 'No'`, In my database I haven't cases with this filters, then when I filter with this params do a query in postgres with this: `("bid_sales"."id" IN (A LOT OF IDS) AND "bid_sales"."id" IN ())` but postgres throw an error because don't support a `IN ()`

Postgres error example:

`postgres=# select * from customer where customer_id in ();
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"`

someone view similar error?